# Redirection .htaccess depending of referer

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, referer

I have a page that is www.example.com/page.html with a link on it that goes to on a blank page www.example.com/folder/link.php?id=123456

For a specific reason, when I'm on the same page but in other language (page will be like www.example.com/page_ro.html) I cannot change this link and need to use rewrite condition to do change that same link.

Let say I need the link to become www.example.com/folder/link.php?id=78910 in this case.

How can I do that in this case ? I've tried this with no success :

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www\.example\.com/page_ro.html [NC]
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI) folder/link\.php?id=123456$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/link.php?id=78910 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match query string using `REQUEST_URI` variable. Use `QUERY_STRING` instead like this inside `/folder/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www\.example\.com/page_ro.html [NC]
RewriteCond %(QUERY_STRING) ^id=123456 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(link\.php)$ $1?id=78910 [NC,L,R=302]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, much appreciated. Your code seems better but not working. No redirection observed. I tested it and it says This variable is not supported: %(THE_REQUEST). Maybe a condition with query string could do that, what you think ?

Comment: I tried in many different options and variant, with target in blank page or same page, it doesn't want to work and I can't figure why :( Thanks for the help, I learned some at least.

Comment: Comment out `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}` line and then in browser enter `www.example.com/folder/link.php?id=123456` to check if it gets redirected

Comment: Apache version is unknown. Might be 2.2 or 2.4 I guess + using Litespeed. Tested your code and commented referer line still won't work. I test this code on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it still saying This variable is not supported: %(QUERY_STRING)

Comment: If it is not Apache then of course whole solution won't work.